# Rotating in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[ultra thick] (-1,0) -- (1,0);
\draw[ultra thick] (0,0) -- (0,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\rotatebox{115}{\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[ultra thick] (-1,0) -- (1,0);
\draw[ultra thick] (0,0) -- (0,2);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

giving

[image]

The picture is supposed to represent the two possible states after throwing a (stylized) nail. The angle in the `\rotatebox` was obtained by trial and error. I was wondering if I could use `tikz` to do the same job without guessing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, Ti*k*Z can do that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[ultra thick] (-1,0) -- (1,0);
\draw[ultra thick] (0,0) -- (0,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate={atan2(1,2)+90}]
\draw[ultra thick] (-1,0) -- (1,0);
\draw[ultra thick] (0,0) -- (0,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

OK, let's let Ti*k*Z do the calculation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[ultra thick] (-1,0) -- (1,0);
\draw[ultra thick] (0,0) -- (0,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[globalize angle/.code={\xdef#1{\n1}}]
% the points (0,2) and (-1,0) are the ones you want to be horizontal
\path let \p1=($(0,2)-(-1,0)$),\n1={180-atan2(\y1,\x1)} in 
[globalize angle=\myangle];
\begin{scope}[rotate=\myangle]
\draw[ultra thick] (-1,0) -- (1,0);
\draw[ultra thick] (0,0) -- (0,2) coordinate(aux);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1, but instead of "tikz can do that", it should be "marmots know trigonometry" :)

Comment: @marmot Quite nice/ Will accept it when I can. Never looked at page 933 of the `pgfmanual` before!

Comment: @samcarter OK OK, I added a second possibility in which calc does the computation. ;-) And of course marmots need to know trigonometry, otherwise they'd get lost in their burrows. ;-)

Comment: Wow! That is an interesting approach!

Comment: @samcarter Both options are basically the same except that I subtracted the vectors by hand in the first proposal (and there is an exchange of x and y, which is however conceptually irrelevant).

Comment: you can also use `[rotate={atan(1/2)+90}]`

Comment: @AndréC Yes, sure. But why would one use that version of `atan` if there is a version available that also takes into account quadrants? What I want to say is that I do not see any reason to use `atan` and not `atan2`.